# Sorting with an SQL UNION query

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have two queries I would like to append in MySQL. I have found that UNION can help me do this, but it is not perfect as it does not retain the order of each appended query. In clear, I would like to do this:

```
(SELECT name,city FROM people WHERE xxx ORDER BY yyy) 
UNION 
(SELECT name,city FROM people WHERE zzz ORDER BY www)
```

but SQL won't execute on the ORDER statements when there is a UNION

One solution would be to add a bogus field to each subquery and order by that field first :

```
(SELECT name,city,'0' as bogus FROM people WHERE xxx) 
UNION 
(SELECT name,city,'1' as bogus FROM people WHERE zzz) 
ORDER by bogus ASC, wwwzzz
```

but this is deeply inefficient as the query has to go through all fields to sort on the bogus field.
Do you know of any workaround?

Thank you

Comment: Actually, that is not "deeply inefficient".  That sounds like exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you. Well each select takes less than 1ms (including the ORDER statement). So I would expect a way to append the two in that same amount of time. But sorting on the bogus field brings the processing time to 500ms, way too much in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use a `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION` ?

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

e.g:

```
(SELECT name,city,'0' as bogus FROM people WHERE xxx) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT name,city,'1' as bogus FROM people WHERE zzz) 
ORDER by bogus ASC, wwwzzz
```

Comment: do you mean using: (SELECT name,city FROM people WHERE xxx ORDER BY yyy) UNION ALL (SELECT name,city FROM people WHERE zzz ORDER BY www) ?  Doesn't seem to work (the order by statements are apparently ignored).

Comment: you are correct....'use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows'

Answer (score 0):

I'm completely winging it here as I only have experience with MsSql so please excuse me if this is useless, but can you store the unordered result set into a temporary table then select that with the required order clause? Or similarly make the union statement a sub/inner query and place the order clause on the outer query?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `UNION` but `UNION ALL`. `UNION` will remove all duplicates and might therefore sort the data.

Also, the global syntax of a SQL query is of this kind:

```
sql_query: compound_statement [order_by_clause]
compound_statement: select_statement [ set_operator compound_statement ]
```

Therefore you can only use ONE `Order By` that is evaluated after `UNION` or `INTERSECTION`. Use subqueries if you want to sort partial results.